# Get First (specific) node with random (optional) subnodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I need the first node of a complex xml by a deep deep subnode with random nodes between.
My XML:

```
<abc>
    <bcd id="1">
        <cde>
            <bcd id="100">
                <cde>
                    <xxx id="998">
                    </xxx>
                </cde>
            </bcd>
        </cde>
    </bcd>
    <bcd id="2">
        <cde>
            <bcd id="101">
                <cde>
                    <bcd id="102">
                        <cde>
                            <xxx id="999">
                            </xxx>
                        </cde>
                    </bcd>
                </cde>
            </bcd>
        </cde>
    </bcd>
</abc>
```

With this XPATH I get only with this design a correct result. the grade of nested is variabel.

```
"//bcd/cde/bcd/cde/xxx[@id='998']"
```

I want a XPATH like that where I get the first bcd (id='1') node:

```
"//[bcd/cde]+/xxx[@id='998']"
```

or first bcd (id='2') node:

```
"//[bcd/cde]+/xxx[@id='999']"
```

regards Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following xpath works for me:

```
/*/bcd[.//xxx/@id='998']
```

Comment: as a result I get the <bcd id="100"> too.

Comment: fixed it so only top elements are selected first