# xpath get specific child

Tags: c#, xpath

let's say I have a html structure like this ->
(note: in my code there are no IDs, i just put them here so it's easier to explain)

```
  <body>
    <table id=a>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table id=b>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id=c>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Using XPath, `//body/table[1]` gives me the inner table with the id "b", but what I really want is it's first child ("c"). Something along th lines of `$("body >table").eq(1)` but i'm using c#. How do I do that using XPath?

Tnx!

EDIT:
it is not an option me to select the [2] element, since this is only a simplified explanation of the problem i'm heaving...

Andrej

Comment: have a look at this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713177/get-first-specific-node-with-random-optional-subnodes

Comment: Isn't the first element 0? //body/table[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element selectors starts from index 1 (and not from 0). Hence you will have to use the xpath query `//body/table[2]`

**Here is the explanation with screen shots.**

For 0 based index node will be null;

[image]

But since the index starts with 1, for indeces 1 and 2 these nodes will be returned

[image]

[image]

Still not convinced? Let's check for the inner table element.

First let's check with 0 based index (again it is going to be null)

[image]

However when the index is 1 it will return the correct node

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//body/table[not(ancestor::td)]
```